# loop through multiple tables' row to grab certain values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to grab the value inside `<span>` of each `<tobdy>`. I know the html is not well-formed, because I didn't write it. That's how SharePoint renders it, and it is in fact bad html. But the question is how do i interate through each  and grab the numeric values inside of brackets i.e 122, 87, and 13  using jQuery? Is this doable?

Here is a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/traFg/

```
<TBODY id=titl386-1_ groupString="%3B%23Completed%3B%23">
    <TR id=group0>
        <TD class=ms-gb colSpan=100 noWrap>
            <A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('386-1_', 'img_386-1_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:">
            <IMG id=img_386-1_ border=0 alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif">&nbsp;Status</A> : Completed
            <SPAN>&nbsp;‎(122) </SPAN>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>

<TBODY id=titl386-1_ groupString="%3B%23InProgress%3B%23">
    <TR id=group0>
        <TD class=ms-gb colSpan=100 noWrap>
            <A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('386-1_', 'img_386-1_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:">
            <IMG id=img_386-1_ border=0 alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif">&nbsp;Status</A> : Completed
            <SPAN>&nbsp;‎(87) </SPAN>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>

<TBODY id=titl386-1_ groupString="%3B%23NotStarted%3B%23">
    <TR id=group0>
        <TD class=ms-gb colSpan=100 noWrap>
            <A onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('386-1_', 'img_386-1_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:">
            <IMG id=img_386-1_ border=0 alt=expand src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif">&nbsp;Status</A> : Completed
            <SPAN>&nbsp;‎(13) </SPAN>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
jQuery('tbody span').each(function()
{
  alert(jQuery(this).text().match(/\d+/));
})
```

Comment: it still returns the text of <a> tag as well. I only want the number